# Redirect after login using module

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

I am using a login module on my site and it is redirecting to some other module I am using for membership/subscription software.
If I connect login for a user with menu item I can say where should redirect after login, but I can´t do that when I use the module. Is there any way I can set URL after login in a module?

I also tried with making Guest group and setting the login module, to be seen only to non registered users in my page, but it is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

Default joomla login module allows you to set the menu on which you want to redirect user after login.

So create a menu for that url on which you want to redirect user and set that menu in the module parameter(Login Redirection Page).

Comment: Yes, but i have set the login module to position and make it visible only on specific page, not to an menu item.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to display the login module in specific page**
Goto backend -> Extensions -> Module manager -> Login form -> Menu Assignment -> Here you can set the login module display in specific page.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need create a group under registered joomla group like "member".
2. Create a new menu.
3. Create menu item and set permission to "member" group, and alias like "member-menu".
4. Redirect login to this url in alias like www.yoursite.com/member-menu
5. Now you can set when this menu/module should be shown in site.